# How do I add a string after the last backslash in another string c++

Tags: c++

So I would like to be able to add a string after the last backslash of a string

**Example:**

```
string1 = C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Desktop\Text File.txt

string2 = "My"
```

I want to add `string2` after the last backslash of `string1`

```
result = C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Desktop\My Text File.txt
                                         ^
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Nothing So far :(

Comment: So please consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: if this is specifically about strings that are file system paths, consider using filesystem related library functions of the runtime environment of whatever operating system you are coding for. with portability in mind, you would for example split by \ or / this is best left to FS abstraction.

Comment: Or even better, to avoid any dependency, if you can use c++17:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem
(see what I did here @YSC)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at those two functions from `std::string`

- [std::string::find_last_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/)
- [std::string::insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/)

Comment: Beat me by a second. I'd would have provided better links though, cplusplus.com is terrible. Try [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of) [instead ;)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert).

Comment: Haha, yeah I know, you're not the only one, but believe or not, I do prefere cplusplus.com :)

Comment: Nobody's perfect :D

Comment: Have you actually read those two links? There will also give you example on how to use those functions

Comment: @MatinPlays "Can you give me an example in code" SO is not a free code writing service.